# colima kubernetes start ends with 'error: no context exists with the name: "colima"'

Tags: macos, kubernetes, apple-silicon, colima

I am running `colima` version 0.5.5 on a Mac M1. When I start Kubernetes via

```
colima kubernetes start
```

the command ends with the following error message:

```
FATA[0093] error starting kubernetes: error running [lima kubectl cluster-info], output: "time=\"2023-06-21T18:15:41Z\" level=fatal msg=\"exec format error\"", err: "exit status 1"
```

When I check my `˜/.kube/kubeconfig.yaml`, this is the content that I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

I can "manually" get the corresponding kubeconfig via

```
colima ssh -- cat /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml > $KUBECONFIG
```

and replace the `default` naming with `colima` and things seem to work as expected afterwards. Still I am wondering what is the proper way of fixing this issue and how do I get a proper kubeconfig after `colima kubernetes start`?

Comment: Try to rename `~/.kube` to `~/.kube.backup` and run `colima kubernetes start` again.

Answer (score 2):

Export KUBECONFIG as follows:

```
export KUBECONFIG="${KUBECONFIG}:${HOME}/kube/config"
```

Use context as colima:

```
kubectl config use-context colima
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).